# page navigation from the left direction

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to ask if you have any experience with having the page arrive from the left instead of right as most of the application have?
I was think that maybe `CarouselPage`but that still has the same navigation. I need exactly the same effect like MasterDetail but whole page not just a menu

Comment: You could use the Flow direction to change it to LeftToRight or RightToLeft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left

Comment: I have tried that but that only set the text to the other direction

Comment: Could you provide more information with code and screenshot for me to test?